# boost::locale icu sortKey

Tags: c++, boost, icu

I am writing code, that making Indexes in database. With ICU library my workflow is:

- string in user locale -> 
  converting to utf8 -> 
  normalize utf8 -> 
  call ICU `ucol_getSortKey` to get Sorting key for building index.

Now I switched to Boost Locale. Can Boost Locale build sort keys like ICU? Or I should call ICU somehow directly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is what Boost Locale knows as `collate_impl::do_[basic_]transform()`:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> do_basic_transform(level_type level,CharType const *b,CharType const *e) const 
{
    icu::UnicodeString str=cvt_.icu(b,e);
    std::vector<uint8_t> tmp;
    tmp.resize(str.length());
    icu::Collator *collate = get_collator(level);
    int len = collate->getSortKey(str,&tmp[0],tmp.size());
    if(len > int(tmp.size())) {
        tmp.resize(len);
        collate->getSortKey(str,&tmp[0],tmp.size());
    }
    else 
        tmp.resize(len);
    return tmp;
}

std::basic_string<CharType> do_transform(level_type level,CharType const *b,CharType const *e) const
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> tmp = do_basic_transform(level,b,e);
    return std::basic_string<CharType>(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
}
```

For performance, it looks like you'd want to call `do_basic_compare`